# RegEx to convert formatted link into html <a> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Because of some poor forward thinking when building my search database, I'm left with some links in the format of: `(Google Homepage)[http://google.com]`

I've been trying to mess with regex in Javascript to convert the format above into a regular HTML link in the format of`<a href="http://google.com">Google Homepage</a>`.

I've been able to pick out the parentheses and brackets via regex, but am having trouble getting regex to replace the parenthesis and brackets with HTML as appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: Show the code you already have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be pretty straightforward.  Basically, just make two capture groups.  One capture group will have the text inside of the parenthesis and the other will have the URL inside the square braces.

```
\((.*?)\)\[(.*?)\]
   #1       #2
```

Then, you can simply stick each captured part into your tag, like this:

```
<a href="\2">\1</a>
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/ytuLDm/1)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```js
var str1="(Google Homepage)[http://google.com]";
    
var pattern=/\((.*)\)\[(.*)\]/;

var str2=str1.replace(pattern,"<a href=\"$2\">$1</a>");

console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

considering that *( )* and *[ ]* define the boundaries, you can try

```
\(([^\)]+)\).*\[([^\]]+)\]
```

\1 will be text and \2 will be link